# Imprimir Reporte Copia a Contabilidad, Copia a Cliente, Copia a Tesoreria en Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, report

Hola estoy imprimiendo las copias de mi reporte con la siguiente linea

```
Docrpt.PrintToPrinter(3, false, 0, 0); );//Imprimo 3 copias
```

pero como hago que la 1 copia tenga un label que diga Contabilidad, Cliente, Tesorería (por decir algo),

Necesito hacer esto desde código, programaticamente que coloque estos labels sin tener que hacer varias secciones como se muestra en este hilo
[crystal-reports-11-how-to-print-different-data-on-multiple-pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336917/crystal-reports-11-how-to-print-different-data-on-multiple-pages)

y sin utilizar parametros.

Comment: El objeto Docrpt que es?

Comment: hola @LuisCarlosDonadoAvella es el documento del reporte.... lo instancie asi... private CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument Docrpt= new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crea dentro del rpt un parametro que se llame destino_copia o como lo quieras llamar

carga el reporte normalmente
con la opcion `setparameter` pasa el nombre de la primera copia
imprime esta copia
cambia el valor del parametro
imprime la segunda copia
imprime nuevamente

y asi para cada copia que se necesite

```
        ReportDocument Reporte = new ReportDocument();

        if (File.Exists(PathReporte))
        {
            Reporte.Load(PathReporte);
            // Asocia el conjunto de datos con el reporte
            Reporte.SetDataSource(origen de datos);


            Reporte.SetParameterValue("TITULO", "Copia a contabilidad");
            Reporte.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0); );//Imprime la primera hoja
            Reporte.SetParameterValue("TITULO", "Copia cliente");
            Reporte.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0); );//Imprime la segunda hoja
            Reporte.SetParameterValue("TITULO", "Copia a tesoreria");
            Reporte.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0); );//Imprime la tercera hoja
```

Comment: eso es precisamente lo que no quiero, parametros, que no utilice parametros para que se le pidan al usuario!!

Comment: el parámetro del reporte se puede enviar programaticamente, el usuario final no intervendria

Comment: @ger actualice la respuesta con un ejemplo de codigo, se envia programaticamente y no hay intervencion del usuario final

Comment: si habia pensado en eso, pero a la final resulta mas practico que elegante! ;)